# Pushing data to jenkins's slave machine before build starts

Tags: windows, tomcat, jenkins, master-slave

I have following configuration:

Jenkins Master - runs on windows+tomacat, Jenkins Slave - runs on gentoo

Slave is reachable by ssh and master can start it without problems. However initiating any connection other way around is not possible.

Problem is that code repositories are on master side and it seems slave tries to fetch from repositories before build and it fails (obviously).

I could push data to slave but I don't know how to execute any command on master side before build script kicks in. Also, I'm not sure is SCM polling initiated on master or on slave machine?

Comment: Author, please define or clarify "data" and "push" :)

Answer (score 2):

Where, there is a [Copy to slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) which can push the files from the master machine to the slave. Additionaly one can choose to use the [Slave Setup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slave+Setup+Plugin) to propagate the environment and all dependencies to the slave while it is starting/connecting.

But it seems like it is rather a conceptual issue with how the file/code repositories are being accessed from the slave machine. Usually this stuff is being handled by SCM plugin and as long you have an accessible repository on the master or any other machine, this should be fairly straight-forward. I do believe it would help if you could describe that part a little better.

Comment: Lukasz is correct. The slave should be polling and accessing SCM on it's own.